# What is the voltage breakdown of saw dust particle board?

Tags: electricity

I have done some testing for the electrical breakdown with the type of wood called particle board. But this particle board is made out of fine sawdust. So I guess what I’m asking is this.

Question: What is the voltage breakdown for sawdust particle board at 1 inch thick?

The reason why I need to know is that my tests have shown that the particle board wood I am using at a thickness of 1 inch is able to withstand 6,000 volts AC. So I know for a fact that this type of wood can handle what I am currently using it for. But I’m building a project that can easily output 20,000 volts.

Notes: Yes I am well aware of the dangers and I have taken the perfect safety protocols to handle this voltage. My project does have an input of exactly 5,520 watts. So I know the pulling arc length can be up to 8 feet according to experimental data. Note that I said “pulling arc length” not dielectric or voltage breakdown.

Thank you for any input as I will appreciate any help with my project for the upcoming year.

Comment: this is a hard enough problem that I would recommend determining the answer with experiments.

Comment: Okay I’ll look into doing experiments with this then. Thank you :)